# Upload a complete project vs. complete while uploaded (GitHub)

Tags: github, project, git-commit

For those that had uploaded their repositories and projects to GitHub already, is it easier to upload first and then finalize the project, or to upload a *"final"* version only (not taking in the account future bug-fixes, if any).

I think of how easy it is to later on substitute the files in the existing repository, if the project is already on GitHub: seems like a **hassle** to delete all files and re-upload them again. Or, the more **commits** - the better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upload first: you can then update your files locally, commit and push.

Git will detect any change/addition/deletion locally, make a new commit, which will then be pushed to your repository.
So no "hassle" involved.

The "more commit, the better" is because you can follow evolution in your code, possibly get back to a previous state, or add fixes.
Plus, it is a good way to save an intermediate state of your project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will certainly do that! I also did not know what these commits mean, but now they make much better sense. And no hassle for sure ;)

Comment: @RockOGOlic on commits: https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/commands/git-commit or https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-commit. Check also https://learngitbranching.js.org/